# React native nested navigation - go back to initial route of stack navigator when the parent drawer route is clicked

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I am using the following navigation setup in my react native project. Here I am using drawer navigation and stack navigation.

```
import MainScreen from '../components/MainScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../components/SettingsScreen';
import FriendsListScreen from '../components/FriendsListScreen';
import FriendProfileScreen from '../components/FriendProfileScreen';

// stack navigator - 1
const MainScreenStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        MainScreen: MainScreen,
        FriendsListScreen: FriendsListScreen,
        FriendProfileScreen: FriendProfileScreen,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'MainScreen',
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "Home"
        },
    }
);

// stack navigator - 2
const SettingsScreenStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        SettingsScreen: SettingsScreen
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "Settings"
        },
    }
);

// drawer navigation (stack navigator 1 + 2)
const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  MainScreen: MainScreenStack,
  SettingsScreen: SettingsScreenStack
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

Scenario:

- From the drawer, I am clicking "Home" link and navigating to MainScreen.
- From the MainScreen, I am clicking a button and navigating to FriendsListScreen.
- From the FriendsListScreen, I am again opening the drawer and clicking the "Home" link. The drawer closes and no navigation happens.

Mock-up:

[image] [image] [image]

Is there a way to navigate back to the MainScreen when I am clicking "Home" link from the drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround for this by creating a custom drawer content as below:

```
import {DrawerItems, SafeAreaView, createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";

const DrawerContent = (props) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{top: 'always', horizontal: 'never'}}>
      <DrawerItems {...props} onItemPress={ ({route, focused}) => {
        if (route.key === "MainScreen") {
          if (route.routes.length === 1) {
            props.navigation.closeDrawer();
          } else {
            props.navigation.navigate(route.routes[0].routeName);
          }
        } else {
          props.onItemPress({route, focused});
        }
      }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
);

const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  MainScreen: MainScreenStack,
  SettingsScreen: SettingsScreenStack
}, {contentComponent: DrawerContent});
```